# Cauchy's Theorem Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to follow "Proof 1" of Cauchy's theorem on prime ordered elements of a group found at the link below.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)

However, I don't see how they determine that $p$ must divide the order of the quotient $G/H$.  I've copied the line in question below.

If p does not divide $|H|$, then it divides the order $[G:H]$ of the quotient group $G/H$

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we have that $|G| = |H| [G:H]$. This is usually proved by showing that all cosets have the same size, and there are $[G:H]$ of them.

Unique prime factorization gives the rest. Since $p$ divides $G$, it must appear in one of the two factors $|H|$ or $[G:H]$.